# Is it safe to reschedule a task before it done when using ScheduledExecutorService?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I want to do some timing tasks using `ScheduledExecutorService`, but time intervals are changeable. I try to reschedule a task before it finished:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {
    public static ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public static int interval = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                interval += 1;
                scheduledExecutorService.schedule(this, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        };
        scheduledExecutorService.schedule(runnable, interval, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

But, I never found anyone do timing tasks using `ScheduledExecutorService` like this, I wonder whether it's safe.

Comment: As written, this code will do nothing.

Comment: Even if you run `runnable`, what you have here isn't rescheduling a task, it's having each task schedule a new one when it ends.  What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: @azurefrog, I want to run a timing task after `delay1`, when the task done, I will re-run the task after delay2, and `delay1` not equals to `delay2` usually. So continue.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use the method `schedule` that executes the task only once, there is nothing wrong with this approach, it will only re-schedule at each iteration the same task with a different delay. For the scheduler it will be seen as a new task scheduled at each iteration, nothing more.